# Customizable Authencation backends not followed by Django's own login testcases. Why?

Tags: django, unit-testing, authentication, testing

I learnt that using [Customizable Authencation backends philosophy](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#specifying-authentication-backends), one can create a website which accepts email addresses as usernames. But after building the corresponding logic and testing that my code is working fine, I found one issue with Django's own testcases. They were failing to follow the Customizable Authencation backend philosophy. Meaning, the testcases [were actually having hardcoded values('username': 'testclient')](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.1.1/django/contrib/auth/tests/views.py#L132) for testing the "login" process. Why is that? Django always discourages Tight Coupling. But whats happening here?

I am not bashing Django by any means! I am a big fan and I will be, for years to come. Just want to know the reason behind this!

Update: As @dmishe pointed out those testcases should validate Django's own functionality. I understood that. But how do I let those "failing testcase" errors NOT show up when I run my testcases or run the whole project test suite?

Comment: I think this question would be more appropriate on the django mailing list. Any answers here will be speculation unless you get an answer from someone fairly involved in the project (which is entirely possible of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As dmishe points out, it is not a problem that the contrib.auth tests test the functionality that is built in to the contrib.auth app. It is a problem that those tests are run for user projects by default, and it is easy to break them via normal settings customization. This is a problem the Django developers are aware of and working on possible solutions.

In the meantime, my solution is to define a simple bash script to test only the apps I want to. So instead of "./manage.py test" I run a script that does "./manage.py test app1 app2 app3...". Not perfect, but it's far from the worst of my problems :-)

**Update**: [This commit](http://code.djangoproject.com/changeset/12420) might interest you.

Comment: I expected to solve this with unittest suites. But still, it needs app1, app2, app3 mentioned scenario. So for now I will go with this. But waiting a better solution....

Comment: @Carl Thanks about the suggestion. I tried the same approach by overriding settings.INSTALLED_APPS and I removed django.contrib.auth from settings.INSTALLED_APPS(for bypassing "auth" tests). It resulted in the non-creation of "auth_user" table, which is needed for all my other tests. So no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem here, django.contrib.auth.tests should test auth app and nothing more.  Thus, it should test built-in backend which is username/password combination.

Comment: @dmishe! You are right. The more I think about it, the more I am inclined towards finding that, its actually true. But I couldn't be expecting Django's testcases to fail, when I am running my testcases. So is there a feasible solution/workaround just to bypass this problem?